# Create Input Fields using json data dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am building a form dynamically from `json` using `jQuery`, and I want to add input fields to my form (e.g. Name, Age, Address, Email).

Here is my code so far:

```
$(function () { 
//Form JSON
var _form=
{
    "sample_form":
    {
        'Title': 'Form using Jquery/JSON',
        'id': 'test_form',
        'action': 'thanks.html',
        'method': 'post',
        'fields':
        [
            {'id':'txtName' , 'caption':'Name' , 'type':'text' , 'required':'true'},
            {'id':'txtNum' , 'caption':'Age' , 'type':'number' , 'required':'false'},
            {'id':'txtAddress' , 'caption':'Address' , 'type':'address' , 'required':'false'},
            {'id':'txtEmail' , 'caption':'Email' , 'type':'email' , 'required':'true'}
        ]
    }
};

//Creating Form

$('div#form2').append(

    //***********************Header*******************
    $('<br/>'),
    $('<span/>').hide(),
    $("<h2/>").text(_form.sample_form.Title),

    //***********************Form*********************
    $('<form/>',
        {
            id: _form.sample_form.id,
            action: _form.sample_form.action,
            method: _form.sample_form.method
        }
    ).append(
        for (var i = 0; i <_form.sample_form.fields.length ; i++)
        {
            $('<input/>',{ type: i.type , required: i.required , id: i.id})
        }           
    )
);});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rL9nsse1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `for` should be out of `.append()`, as @giorgio has already mentioned;
- inside `for`, `i.type` (and others) should replaced with `_form.sample_form.fields[i].type`.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rL9nsse1/1/).

Changed part of code:

```
//Creating Formm

var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i <_form.sample_form.fields.length ; i++)
{
    var element = _form.sample_form.fields[i];
    arr.push($('<input/>',{ type: element.type , required: element.required , id: element.id}));
}

$('div#form2').append(

    //***********************Header*******************
    $('<br/>'),
    $('<span/>').hide(),
    $("<h2/>").text(_form.sample_form.Title),

    //***********************Form*********************

    $('<form/>',
        {
            id: _form.sample_form.id,
            action: _form.sample_form.action,
            method: _form.sample_form.method
        }
    ).append(arr)
);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You have added a for-loop as a parameter of the append function. You should get it out, and append on each iteration. Example:

```
var myForm = $('<form/>');
for(var i = 0; i <_form.sample_form.fields.length ; i++)
{
    myForm.append('<input/', { /* paramaters */ });
}
```